# Finding representations $N = ma^2 + nb^2 = mc^2 + nd^2$ given factorization of $N = pq$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

If we have a representation of $N = ma^2 + nb^2 = mc^2 + nd^2$ in two different ways, we can get its factorization as $(N, ad+bc) \cdot \frac{N}{(N, ad+bc)}$ where $(x,y)$ is the GCD of $x$ and $y$.

How do we do the reverse?

Suppose we have the factorization of $N = pq$. How can we get the two representations of $N$ of the form $N = ma^2 + nb^2 = mc^2 + nd^2$.

**What I have so far.**

If $N = ma^2 + nb^2 = mc^2 + nd^2$ then

$$
(d^2-b^2)N = m(ad-bc)(ad+bc)
$$

If we take $m = d^2 - b^2$ then we can factor $m$ and fix $d, b$.

Also, we have
$$
N = (ad - bc)(ad + bc)
$$

Taking

$$
ad - bc = p\\
ad + bc = q
$$

we get

$$
a = \frac{q+p}{2d} \\
c = \frac{q-p}{2b}
$$

This means $p,q$ have same parity and $d|(q+p)$ and $b|(q-p)$ for $a,c$ to be integers. How do we prove that $a,c$ are integers?